# How to set the shutter time but leave the ISO (sensitivity) on auto on android

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, exposure-time

I am building an Android app with the Camera2 API that uses short shutter times, 1/1000 and 1/2000.
I can set the SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME without any problem. But I want to keep the ISO (SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) on auto mode.

To set the shutter speed I use the following code:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, EXPOSURE);
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, surfaceView.getmBackgroundHandler());
```

This code works OK, but because the CONTROL_AE_MODE is set to CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF the ISO (SENSOR_SENSITIVITY) has to be set manually also. And this is what I don't want, I want to keep the ISO on auto.

Is there any way to accomplish this or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently supported by the API. Your only choices are to run in full manual or full auto, unfortunately.